# Unable to click on tree element through pywinauto

Tags: pywin32, pywinauto

I'm unable to click on tree view, please see snap:

[image]

For this I am using this code

```
    evidence_treeview = context.new_evidence_window[u'TreeView']
    time.sleep(2)
    evidence_treeview.get_item([u'Evidence'], False).click()
```

Comment: Which backend is used? What is the full traceback of the error? It's better to switch `Inspect.exe` to UI Automation mode.

Comment: Backend is win32 Please see the error   {"name": "Decrypt NSF with password -- @1.1 ", "status": "broken", "statusDetails": {"message": "AttributeError: The control does not have a __getitem__ method for item access (i.e. ctrl[key]) so maybe you have requested this in error?\n"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what is `context` variable? Is it `WindowSpecification` object? If yes, this is incorrect for "win32" backend, because it doesn't support more than 2 levels of window specifications (you requested 3 levels). By the way UIA backend supports 3+ levels, but TreeViewWrapper has different implementation there.

I suspect this code should work (but I'n not 100% sure without previous lines):

```
evidence_treeview = context[u'TreeView']
time.sleep(2)
evidence_treeview.get_item([u'Evidence'], False).click()
```

Comment: I was not getting context value correctly, after correcting this its working fine. I wrote code like this context.new_evidence_window = context.ftk_app.AfxFrameOrView140u
context.new_evidence_window.set_focus()
time.sleep(2)
evidence_treeview = context.new_evidence_window[u'TreeView']
time.sleep(2)
evidence_treeview.get_item([u'Evidence'], False).click()